# Most efficient way to delete rows from pandas df based on list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have main df:

```
   ID             title       grade1       grade2
 "1111"        "something"      1             2
 "2222"        "something1"     2             2
 "3333"        "something2"     1             1
 "something3"    "8865"         1             1
 "4444"        "something3"     1             2
 "5555"        "something4"     1             1
 "6666"        "something5"     2             2
 "somethingX"  "8888"           1             1
```

And as u can see it's thera are mixed up values in columns 1 and 2

So what I do:

1. put all wrong names to new df:  `temp = df[df['ID'].str.len() > 4]`
2. create list from new df: `listToMove = temp['ID].unique()`
3. delete all records from df by for: `df = df[df['ID'] != listToMove[i])`
4. change column plce in temp `df`
5. append temp df to df.

But i think it's not the best practice. it's work fine... but that for... i think it's slow, and I can do it faster.

Any suggestion?

Result shoud be:

```
        ID             title       grade1       grade2
     "1111"        "something"      1             2
     "2222"        "something1"     2             2
     "3333"        "something2"     1             1
     "8865"        "something3"     1             1
     "4444"        "something3"     1             2
     "5555"        "something4"     1             1
     "6666"        "something5"     2             2
     "8888"        "somethingX"     1             1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can swap values by condition in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
m1 = df['ID'].str.len() != 4
    
df.loc[m1, ['ID', 'title']] = df.loc[m1, ['title', 'ID']].to_numpy()
print (df)
     ID       title  grade1  grade2
0  1111   something       1       2
1  2222  something1       2       2
2  3333  something2       1       1
3  8865  something3       1       1
4  4444  something3       1       2
5  5555  something4       1       1
6  6666  something5       2       2
7  8888  somethingX       1       1
```